# Crear un archivo desde terminal y tomar el nombre - PHP

Tags: php, cmd

Les cuento que estoy creando mis archivos `php` desde la terminal CMD, pero no sé como hacer para que al crear un archivo la clase tome el nombre del archivo que estoy creando.

`> php crearArchivo.php "nombre_del_archivo"`

crearArchivo.php

```
$fh = fopen("nombre_del_archivo.php", 'w') or die("Se produjo un error al crear el archivo");

$texto = <<<_END
<?php

class Saludo extends Database{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->database = new Database();
    }
}

?>
_END;

fwrite($fh, $texto) or die("No se pudo escribir en el archivo");
fclose($fh);
echo "Se ha escrito sin problemas";
```

Ademas, también tengo este error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number on...

Hace referencia a la línea donde esta `$this->db = new Database();`.

Se agradece la ayudita. Besos!

Comment: Documentación de PHP [$argv](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.argv.php), incluso hay un ejemplo de cómo capturar los argumentos de la consola.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo por que es interesante pero tampoco puedo resolver el `$this->db = new Database();`. Si resulevo eso te lo paso. Lo que dice @aeportugal es correcto, pero hay que pasar `1` en el arreglo => `$argv[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí pude resolverlo.

1 - paso el array `$argv[1]` para tomar el texto desde la consola de comando.

2 - `strtolower()` para que la primera letra del archivo `.php` este en minúscula.

3 - `ucfirst` para que la primera letra de la clase este en mayúscula.

4 - el error que tenes con el `$this->database = new Database()` lo solucione pasandolo como un string en la varieble `$objeto`.

```
<?php

$file = $argv[1];

$fh = fopen(strtolower($file).'.php', 'w') or die("Se produjo un error al crear el archivo");

$classname = ucfirst($file);
$objeto = '$this->database = new Database()';

$texto = <<<_END
<?php

class $classname extends Database {

    public function __construct() {
        $objeto
    }

}

?>
_END;

fwrite($fh, $texto) or die("No se pudo escribir en el archivo");
fclose($fh);
echo "Se ha escrito sin problemas";

?>
```

Comment: Mil gracias Sebas  !!!! Siiii, los archivos los creo en minúscula así que me viene bárbaro 

Answer (score 0):

En el manual https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php. puedes encontrar esto:

> "Nowdoc es a los string con comillas simples lo mismo que Heredoc lo
> es a los string con comillas dobles. Un nowdoc se especifica de forma
> análoga a un heredoc, pero no se realiza ningún análisis dentro del
> nowdoc"

En el caso de utilizar Heredoc, va a intentar interpretarte el $this. Pero en tu caso no estas en una clase, sino en un "texto" que va a contener esa definición. En su lugar, mejor que utilices Nowdoc.

En el ejemplo que te pone en el manual se ve la diferencia:

```
echo <<<'EOT'
Mi nombre es "$nombre". Estoy escribiendo un poco de $foo->foo.
Ahora, estoy escribiendo un poco de {$foo->bar[1]}.
Esto debería mostrar una 'A' mayúscula: \x41
EOT;
```

esto se interpreta como:

```
Mi nombre es "$nombre". Estoy escribiendo un poco de $foo->foo.
Ahora, estoy escribiendo un poco de {$foo->bar[1]}.
Esto debería mostrar una 'A' mayúscula: \x41
```

que es lo que vas a querer escribir en el archivo.